# Insert data to mysql doesn't work from php

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have the following PHP code:

```
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
    $insert_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO articles(articleTitle, articleContent, typeID)
    VALUES
   ('$_POST[articleTitle]','$_POST[articleContent]',$_POST[articleType])");
    }
```

typeID => is number, the other values are text.

There is no error in this code, but the insert query doesn't work (I have no idea why because I don't get any error message).

How can I fix it?

Comment: mysql_* functions have been deprecated. Use PDO or mysqli

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code.

1. It's open to SQL injectoion
2. mysql_* functions have been deprecated

This code is untested but should give you an idea:

```
try
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your_database_name', $user, $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO Persons (articleTitle, articleContent, typeID) VALUES (:articleTitle, :articleContent, :articleType)');
    $sth->execute($_POST);

    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
}
```

Have a look at this article on [Why you Should be using PHP’s PDO for Database Access](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
if(isset($_POST[articleTitle])) {
    $insert_query = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO Persons (articleTitle, articleContent,typeID)
    VALUES
    ('$_POST[articleTitle]','$_POST[articleContent]',$_POST[articleType])");
}
```